# Mirth is reading too slow from disk

Tags: mirth

I am using Mirth 3.0.1 version. I am reading a file (using File Reader) having 34,000 records. Every record is having 45 columns and are pipe(|) separated. Mirth is taking too much time while reading the file from the disk. Mirth is installed on the same server where file is located.Earlier, I was facing the java head space issue which I resolved after setting the -Xms1024m -Xmx4096m in files mcserver.vmoptions & mcservice.vmoptions. Now I have to solve reading performance issue. Please find in attachment the channel for the same.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this problem is highly dependent on the solution itself. As an example, if you are doing transformations when you benchmark, it might be that the problem is not with reading the files, but rather with doing massive amounts of filtering and transformations in Mirth. Since Mirth converts everything you configure into basically one gigantic Javascript that executes on the server, it might just as well be that this is causing the performance problem. Pre-processor scripts might also create a problem if you do something that causes Mirth to read the whole file.

It migh also be that your 34.000 lines in the file contains huge quantities of information, simply making the file very big and extensive to process. If every record in the file is supposed to create new messages within Mirth, you might also want to check your batch settings for the reader.

And in addition to this, the performance of the read operations from disk is of course affected a lot by the infrastructure and hardware of the platform itself. You did mention that you are reading the files locally and that you had to increase the memory for Mirth. All of this could of course be a problem in itself. To make a benchmark you would want to compare this to something else. Maybe write a small Java program to just read the file to compare performance outside of Mirth.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @max_ You are absolutely right. The low volume of Mirth related questions doesn't give me enough opportunity to hunt for reputation in order to comment. So I'm in a bit of a catch 22 on this "should i ignore the question" or "should I abuse the system to get more information to help". Sorry about that.

Comment: @max_ As suggested on meta, I change the questions to sound more like an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions.
I have used router.routeMessage('channelName','PartOfMsg') to route the 5000 records(from one channel to second channel) from the file having 34000 of records. This has helped to read faster from the file and processing the records at the same time.

For Mirth Community, below is the code to route the msg from one channel to other channel, this solution is also for the requirement if you have bulk of records to process in batches

```
In Source Transformer,

debug = "ON";

XML.ignoreWhitespace = true;

logger.debug('Inside source transformer "SplitFileIntoFiles" of channel: SplitFile');

var 
subSegmentCounter = 0,
xmlMessageProcessCounter = 0,
singleFileLimit = 5000,
isError = false,
xmlMessageProcess = new XML(<delimited><row><column1></column1><column2></column2></row></delimited>),

newSubSegment = <row><column1></column1><column2></column2></row>,

totalPatientRecords = msg.children().length();
logger.debug('Total number of records found in the patient input file are: ');
logger.debug(totalPatientRecords);

try{
for each (seg in msg.children())
{

xmlMessageProcess.appendChild(newSubSegment);

xmlMessageProcess['row'][xmlMessageProcessCounter] = msg['row'][subSegmentCounter];

if (xmlMessageProcessCounter == singleFileLimit -1)
{
logger.debug('Now sending the 5000 records to the next channel from channel DOR Batch File Process IHI');   

router.routeMessage('DOR SendPatientsToMedicare',xmlMessageProcess);

logger.debug('After sending the 5000 records to the next channel from channel DOR Batch File Process IHI');

xmlMessageProcessCounter = 0;

delete xmlMessageProcess['row'];
}
subSegmentCounter++;
xmlMessageProcessCounter++;
}// End of FOR loop
}// End of try block

catch (exception)
{
logger.error('The exception has been raised in source transformer "SplitFileIntoFiles" of channel: SplitFile');
logger.error(exception);

globalChannelMap.put('isFailed',true);

globalChannelMap.put('errDesc',exception);

return true;
}


if (xmlMessageProcessCounter > 1)
{
try
{
logger.debug('Now sending the remaining records to the next channel from channel DOR Batch File Process IHI');  
router.routeMessage('DOR SendPatientsToMedicare',xmlMessageProcess);
logger.debug('After sending the remaining records to the next channel from channel DOR Batch File Process IHI');
delete xmlMessageProcess['row'];
}

catch (exception)
{
logger.error('The exception has been raised in source transformer "SplitFileIntoFiles" of channel: SplitFile');
logger.error(exception);

globalChannelMap.put('isFailed',true);

globalChannelMap.put('errDesc',exception);

return true;
}

}
return true;
// End of JavaScript
```

Hope, this will help.